# SQL query for occurrence

Tags: sql

Please can you solve this table for the same question. To select the average review length of the 2nd review of each reviewer with at least 2 reviews.

```
ReviewID    Listing_id  ReviewLength    Reviewer
------------------------------------------------
1              1230          3            sdf
2              3450         35            sgr
3              4450         45            tyu
4              3560         67            gdh
5              4560         78            gdj
6              4450         65            dgj
7              4450         32            bhf
8              3560          3            kkh
9              1230          6            dtg
10             3430          7            cgfh
11             4450         13            kld
12             1230         69            dhh
13              560         86            dch
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: What is the output you expect?

Comment: Rows in a relational database are **NOT** sorted. There is no such thing as "the second review" unless you have some column that defines the order of the reviews. Does `reviewid` or `listing_id` define the order of the reviews?

Comment: For a _reviewer_ to have at least two reviews, the same _reviewer_ value would need to appear more than once in the table. This is not the case in the sample data you posted. Each _reviewer_ appears exactly once.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses window functions to compute the average length of the second review of each reviewer (if nay). I made the assumption that column `ReviewID` can be used to sort the reviews. Also I find that this condition is redundant: *2nd review of each reviewer with at least 2 reviews.*: if a reviewer has a 2nd review, then he did perform at least 2 reviews.

```
SELECT AVG(ReviewLength) avg_review_length
FROM (
    SELECT
        ReviewLength,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Reviewer ORDER BY ReviewID) rn
    FROM mytable 
) x
WHERE rn = 2
```